# How to point to the latest master of a project repository using node package.json?

Tags: node.js

How can I point to the master of a particular project repository using a node `package.json`? For instance, I am using `karma-jasmine` package in my project and is referred as `"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0"` in `package.json`. Now, the latest version of `karma-jasmine` is `1.1.1`. But there is a bug which has been patched on their repository which is in the project's master branch. But it is not yet part of any release.

Could I by any means point to the `master` of the project repository so that I could have the access to the fixed code rather than waiting until they release a newer version? Is it possible at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question you can load from github directly by doing

`npm install karma-runner/karma-jasmine`

or

`npm install karma-runner/karma-jasmine#branch`

To your issue though, https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine lists 1.1.1 as the current which matches the GitHub repo version for master and that is the latest commit.

So you most likely you can just do

`npm install --save-dev karma-jasmine@latest`

Answer (score 1):

NPM modules are only available on the registry once they've been published there by their authors.  If the project in question has merged the fix to master, but not yet published an updated release to the registry, there's no way for you to get it short of cloning their repo and building it yourself.

Comment: That's what I thought. I wish there was a sneaky way to do it.